# C input and out parameters of a function

Tags: c

For a class project I am writing, my teacher's style guide for functions says that "input parameters must appear before out parameters." I am not too sure what they mean by this?

Comment: In `(a, b)` `a` is appearing before `b`.

Comment: `int func(int input, int *output)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have a function

```
void foo(int a, int b, int* c)
{
    *c = a+b;
}
```

In the above case a and b are inputs while c is an output.

Generally you use "outputs" in this way if you are returning an array.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any advice on the order of primitive variables and pointers/array (disgregarding input/output order) ?

Comment: Whatever makes the most sense when you're declaring it works best. Grouping parametres by type makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't actually have "input" and "output" parameters, at least not directly. (Some languages do.) All arguments are passed by value, meaning that the function gets the value of the argument, but any modifications to the parameter are invisible to the caller.

(Terminology: A *parameter" is a named object in the body of a function, defined between the parentheses; an *argument* is an expression in a function call. Each argument is evaluated and the resulting value is assigned to the corresponding parameter.)

However, you can simulate "output" parameters using pointers. For example:

```
void foo(int in, int *out);
```

The pointer is passed by value, but the function can assign a value *via* the pointer to `*out`, which will be visible to the caller. (`out` can also be used as an input parameter, which is common for large types where passing a pointer is more efficient, or as an input/output parameter.)

So "input parameters must appear before out parameters" probably means that non-pointer parameters should appear before pointer parameters used to return values indirectly.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to use a pointer as both an input and output for a function? So the value pointed to is set before calling the function, which reads and then sets the value pointed to?

Comment: @Vic No, that's fine. A trivial example: `void increment(int *n) { (*n) ++; }`

Comment: Ah, incrementing makes sense. I don't think I've come across it used for a calculation before, e.g. `void square(float *n);`

Comment: @Vic: As I said, it's a trivial example. And a square function would more reasonably be written as `float square(float x) { return x * x; }`. But more generally, something like `void update(some_type *object);` is fine. Or even `int update(some_type *object);` where the returned value can be used to indicate an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is *usually* for `void` functions.

```
void some_function (int input_1, int input_2, char* output)
{
    /* Do things with input_1 and input_2. */

    /* Modify "output". */
}
```

The code I just gave is very vague, and the input/output parameters in a void function can be applied in many ways.

Comment: Very true. I will edit my answer accordingly. Most people modify the parameters using void functions, so I may have overlooked that.