# Program C counting total number of odd digits

Tags: c, function, loops

I'm writing a C program that counts the number of odd digits from user input.

Eg.

Please enter the number: 12345

countOddDigits(): 3

```
int countOddDigits(int num);
int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("Please enter the number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("countOddDigits(): %d\n", countOddDigits(number));
    return 0;
}
int countOddDigits(int num)
{
    int result = 0, n;
    while(num != 0){
        n = num % 10;
        if(n % 2 != 0){
            result++;
        }
       n /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code is not working. 
Can someone tell me where does it go wrong?

Comment: What *happens* when you run it? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And please reas [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: `n /= 10;` ==> `num /= 10;`

Comment: Get rid of `n` and simply use `num` instead. It's not like you need `num` to stay constant at the end of the function and it only generates confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few mistakes in your code. Here is a working version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int countOddDigits(int n); 
int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("Please enter the number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("countOddDigits(): %d\n", countOddDigits(number));
    return 0;
}

int countOddDigits(int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    while(n != 0){
        if(n % 2 != 0)
            result++;
        n /= 10;
    }   
    return result;
}
```

1. You are mixing `n` and `num` together - there is no need for two variables.
2. `n%=10` is just causing mistakes - you need to check the last digit `if(n%2!=0)` and then move to the next one `n/=10`, that's all.

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to use a void function?

Comment: Well, you have to get the `result` value out of the function somehow. You could use output parameter instead of returning it.

Comment: @BEX Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403940/c-input-and-out-parameters-of-a-function

Comment: I tried changing it to void countOddDigits(int num, int *result), all "result" to "*result" and deleted the return statement but it doesn't output the value. Is there anything I should add to my code?

Comment: It won't output the value - functions with `void` return type don't output anything. You need to create result variable in the `main` function. Then call the `countTheOddDigits` function. The function will **modify** the `result` variable and then you can print it out.

Comment: I recommend you to read something about pointers, because you won't really understand how output parameters work otherwise. Eg. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Answer (score 1):

Looping variable is not correct.  Your outer loop is

`while (num !=0)`

but the **num** variable is never decremented; the final statement decrements the **n** variable.  My guess is you want to initialize

```
int n = num;
while (n != 0 )
{ ...
  n/= 10;
}
```